# What does the middle side in the fifa 14 choosing controls mean?

Tags: fifa-14

So when you want to play a game there would be 3 sides that have keyboards and controllers as pictures. the page is before you choose your outfit. So what does the middle side mean?

Comment: No offense, but you seriously could not figure that out by yourself?

Comment: I was not sure so dont tell me that. And i did think that.

Answer (score 1):

The middle side represents that you dont wanna control either team on the match,
people use it when they want to simulate a match IA vs IA.

Or if you have 2 controllers plugged in and only want to play with one, you choose the side you want with one controller and put the other on the middle section.